# how to get rows from two tables using like command

Tags: mysql

I have two tables users and admin which contains same column emp_code.

I have a input field with button. I need to enter emp_code in input field.I need to get the rows from two tables which contains emp_code which i entered.

I need sql query to get the rows from two tables which contains emp_code which i entered.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried this query SELECT * FROM users WHERE emp_code LIKE 'bssb%';

Comment: i dont know how to use two table in one query

Comment: You should probably use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php).

Comment: give me query @cakan

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are new to DB Queries.
Well here is another simplest solution, (without join)

```
SELECT * FROM USERS, ADMIN
WHERE USERS.EMP_CODE = ADMIN.EMP_CODE
AND USERS.EMP_CODE like 'your_emp_code_here'
```

Comment: get this error : Column 'EMP_CODE' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all the users from user and admin table which have emp code similar to code given in the input field. Then you have to use "Union" in the sql query (Assuming both tables have the same columns):

```
SELECT username FROM ADMIN
WHERE EMP_CODE LIKE 'your_emp_code_here'
UNION
SELECT username  FROM USERS
WHERE EMP_CODE LIKE 'your_emp_code_here'
```

Comment: getting this error : The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: then use common columns in select statement. Above query edited.

Comment: If you want more then one column then use multiple columns in select statement but both select statement should have same columns